# how to express nested where statements for postgres in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, where-clause

I have a `Job` ressource, with `example` as integer variable. `example` is the id of a `Post`, which belongs to a `User`. Now i want to query through every `Job` record, where the `example` equals a `Post` where the id of this post equals the `current_user` like:

`@jobs = Job.where(example: Post.where(user_id: current_user.id)).all`

This syntax seems to be "correct" for sqlite in test env but breaks in postgres on a heroku production server.

Postgres is giving the following error when trying the syntax above:

`HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

how to express that in the rails way?

Comment: Can you share Job model?

Answer (score 0):

Found the bug.. `example` is a string and not an integer.